# Unable to uninstall a deprecated Homebrew formular

Tags: homebrew

During an upgrade of elasticsearch, I noticed I have an old homebrew formula installed called "[elasticsearch13](http://www.braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/formula/elasticsearch13)".

```
$ brew list | grep elastic
elasticsearch13
```

This formula has been deprecated and **removed**. When trying to uninstall this formula, I'm given the warning:

```
$ brew uninstall elasticsearch13
Error: No available formula with the name "elasticsearch13"
```

The doctor's not telling me much...

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/python2.7/greenlet/greenlet.h

Warning: Your Xcode (8.0) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

No worries, solved it myself:

Find the last commit of github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions (before it was removed) and download it:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/2fabaf8210b1c9addc20e87da8c961aced58e2eb/elasticsearch13.rb > elasticsearch13.rb
```

The run the uninstall script:

```
brew uninstall elasticsearch13
rm elasticsearch13.rb
```